# Display value from html table with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this structure of  table and I want to display the value of the input type text, I tried this attempt but it didn't work.

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Adress</th>
    <th>display</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="text" class="name"> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" class="adress"> </td>
    <td> <input type="button" value="display" class="show"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="text" class="name"> </td>
    <td> <input type="text" class="Adress"> </td>
    <td> <input type="button" value="display" class="show"> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

file.js

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(".show").click(function(data){
        alert($(this).parent().prev().prev().text());
        alert($(this).parent().prev().text());
    });
});
```

Comment: Which input? Please review the "selectors" documentation of jQuery.

Comment: For an input element, you need to use `.val()` instead of `.text()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st - in your second input you have class="Adress" it should be class="adress"

```
$(document).ready(function (){

        $(".show").click(function(data){
           alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.name').val());
           alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.adress').val());
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate to the row element using `parent()` (one to go to `td`, second to go to the `tr`). Then you can access to the text fields like this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    $(".show").click(function(data){
        var row = $(this).parent().parent();
        var name = $('.name', row);
        var adress = $('.adress',row);
        alert(name.val());
        alert(adress.val());
    });
```

});

Here is JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ab618s7v/